# A href URL with div ID wildcard

Tags: url, html, anchor, href, wildcard

Is there a way to open a page and jump to a div ID when only part of the ID is known?

```
eg: http://wp-site.com/webpage.php#div-id-name-xxxx
```

where 'xxxx' is a set of numbers that are impossible to know until after the page has loaded.

I'm using a shortcode which generates a page element within a div where the beginning of the ID is standard (eg: tabs-bottom, contact-form, etc) followed by a unique number that is randomly generated each time the page loads.

I want to be able to link to the div on that page from another page, but with part of the ID being dynamic, I'm having trouble doing so. I thought passing a wildcard in the URL might be the way to go...

Any ideas?

**ps: the pages are part of a Wordpress based site, if that helps.**